# Laravel - adding new migrations to system

Tags: php, laravel, database, laravel-artisan

I have a Laravel application that I am building which is a medical claims management system. I have created three migrations, create_roles_table, create_claim_statuses_table and create_claims_table, and run the migrations using 'php artisan migrate' to build the table structures in the database. Here's my question: I would like to come back and add more migrations in the future to create other tables, such as 'create_patients_table' and 'create_practices_table'. However, when I try to do this, it says 'table already found' and tries to run the existing migrations that are there already. This is the case even when I delete those migration files from the folder. What is causing Laravel to do this and is there a way of resetting the system's memory so that it only runs the new ones?

Thanks,
Robert

Comment: Once you run `php artisan migrate` does the migrations table in your database have entries for your tables?

Comment: When you run `php artisan migrate`, it _should_ run any migrations that haven't been run. These are tracked in a `migrations` table that is auto-generated on the first run of `php artisan migrate`. Migrations by default are a forward-moving process; as you add new migrations, run `php artisan migrate`. If you need to undo migration(s), run `php artisan migrate:rollback --step=X`. If you need to refresh _ALL_ migration, run `php artisan migrate:refresh`, etc. Full details here: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/migrations. Your use case does not match what _should_ be happening...

Comment: To reset the migration you can use `php artisan migrate:fresh`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
php artisan migrate:rollback
```

to revert the current tables and again execute

```
php artisan migrate
```

Or maybe you can execute only the migration that you need with this command

```
php artisan migrate --path=database/migrations/you_file_migration_table.php
```

Comment: It's probably important to note that `migrate:rollback` can be destructive, as it may delete data.